# ERROR: syntax error at or near | modify('replace value of | PostgresSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query for updating xml column value it may have or may not have an existing value. I have tried this query but it is giving me syntax error don't know why. I am not SQL expert i am just working with existing code.

**Error**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4: SET user_prop.modify('replace value of ("//PREF/NOTIFICATION...
                            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 199
```

**Query**

```
UPDATE user
SET user_prop.modify('replace value of ("//PREF/NOTIFICATIONS/@ASK_YOUR_INSTR") with ("TRUE")') where username='1038125@';
```

**XML Value**

```
<PROP>
<ACL DENY="CREATECOURES"></ACL>
<PREF>
    <NOTIFICATIONS ASK_YOUR_INSTR="FALSE" />
</PREF>
</PROP>
```

Answer (score 1):

The SET part of an UPDATE needs an assignment, e.g.

```
update foo
  set bar = bar + 1
where id = 1;
```

You haven't told us what your function `modify()` does, but if it returns the modified XML value, then I guess you are looking for:

```
UPDATE user
  SET the_column = user_prop.modify('....')
where username='1038125@';
```

Comment: Well, I have corrected that mistake. And the modify() function is supposed to modify the value of the xml node

Comment: @M.WaseemUllahKhan without showing us what your `modify()` function does this is impossible to answer.

Comment: I found this function on the internet I thought it may work but it seems Postgres do not have a method to update the value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the answer

```
UPDATE HR_XML
SET Salaries.modify('replace value of 
(/Salaries/Marketing/Employee[@ID=("2")]/Salary/text())[1] with ("60000")')
```

can you try to remove the quotes from the `//PREF/NOTIFICATIONS/@ASK_YOUR_INSTR`

Comment: This is invalid SQL